# Double Integral Limits of Integration Without Graphing

Tags: calculus

Usually I change the order & limits of integration in double integrals by graphing the curves in the domain & working it out from the geometry.

However in this double integral:

$$ \smallint_0^{\alpha} \tfrac{T(E)dE}{\sqrt{\alpha - E}} = \sqrt{2m} \int_0^\alpha \int_0^E [\tfrac{dx_2}{dU} - \tfrac{dx_1}{dU}] \tfrac{dUdE}{\sqrt{(\alpha - E)(E - U)}}$$

I have no idea how the following happens:

$$ \sqrt{2m} \int_0^\alpha \int_0^E [\tfrac{dx_2}{dU} - \tfrac{dx_1}{dU}] \tfrac{dUdE}{\sqrt{(\alpha - E)(E - U)}} = \sqrt{2m} \int_0^\alpha \int_U^\alpha [\tfrac{dx_2}{dU} - \tfrac{dx_1}{dU}] \tfrac{dUdE}{\sqrt{(\alpha - E)(E - U)}}$$

as is done in [section 12 of Landau](http://books.google.ie/books?id=bE-9tUH2J2wC&pg=PA27&lpg=PA27&dq=landau%20%22determination%20of%20the%20potential%20energy%20from%20the%20period%20of%20oscillation%22&source=bl&ots=lP1vrgGXT-&sig=haVea2mcubtfK1gTvY7cHZ6tgG0&hl=en&sa=X&ei=7SEXUomtOvKd7gaMt4CQBw&ved=0CDgQ6AEwAg#v=onepage&q=landau%20%22determination%20of%20the%20potential%20energy%20from%20the%20period%20of%20oscillation%22&f=false).

So I guess the question is how does one do this in general without graphing anything, i.e. change the limits of integration, in a way that makes sense of the above integral? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

There is a misprint in that formula. The domain of integration is $\{ (U,E) \colon 0 < E < \alpha, 0 < U < E \}$. Now if you start with $U$ then you can see that $U$ is always between $0$ and $\alpha$ and $E$ is larger than $U$. So
$$\int_0^{\alpha} \int_0^E f(U,E)dUdE = \int_0^{\alpha} \int_U^{\alpha} f(U,E)dEdU.$$

Comment: A misprint is in your post actually, the book has the correct form of this formula.

Comment: Is that perhaps "$E$ is *larger* than $U$"?

Comment: @JonathanY., of course. Corrected. Thanks.